# Build a fake course catalog

Tags: r, data-structures, dynamically-generated

I have really ugly code that takes a LONG time to run. First if builds a list of fake college courses:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(gtools)
rm(list = ls())


course_subjects<-c("Math", "English", "History","Writing","Engineering","Chemistry","Biology","Business","Physics","Economics","Music","Art")


course_numbers<-sprintf("%04d",seq(900,2050,by = 15)) 
course.offerings<-expand.grid("course_subject" = course_subjects,
                            "course_number" = course_numbers)%>%
  mutate(course = paste0(course_subject,"-",course_number),# specify the course name
         offerings = ceiling(8.75*rchisq(length(course_numbers)*length(course_subjects),0.0001,3)+1))%>%#randomly assign the number of sections, assume the distribution of number of sections offered is skewed right
  dplyr::select(course,
                offerings)


rm(course_subjects)
rm(course_numbers)
```

then create codes for the available lecture halls on 10 campuses designated by LETTERS, and with 20 rooms per campus

```
lecture.halls<-expand.grid("campus" = LETTERS[1:10],
                           "classroom" = sprintf("%03d",seq(1,20,by = 1)))%>%
  mutate(lecture_hall = paste0(campus,classroom))%>%
  dplyr::select(lecture_hall)
```

One last step before the real code-f*ckery starts. Make the number of sections offered for each of these courses be kinda skewed so you have really popular classes that need a lot of sections and courses where there aren't a lot of sections offered, and create unique section identifiers.

```
expanded.offerings<-as.data.frame(course.offerings[rep(row.names(course.offerings), course.offerings$offerings),])%>%
  group_by(course)%>%
  mutate(section = paste0(course,"-",sprintf("%03d",row_number(course))))%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  dplyr::select(section)
```

As promised, this is the section I feel I'm doing something just profoundly stupid. I use a for loop to go one by one and fill the first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, and seventh time block available for each day of the week and remove rows from the course offering data set that I sample so as to ensure that if I have the same course taught in one classroom in a day they are at least in different sections and the illusion of sampling from a real course catalogue can continue. I know if I knew more about the mapping functions it would probably be quicker and more efficient, I just need a way to populate a matrix by sampling from a 1d list. Note: I chose the for loop because I want to build some complexity with the data generating so I can build schedules that accommodate courses with different attributes like number of meeting days in a week, and length of class time, etc....

Anyway, the for loop that generates data that kinda look like what I'm going for is below

```
for(i in 1:nrow(lecture.halls)){
  #MONDAY COURSES
  mon1.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$mon1[i]<-expanded.offerings[mon1.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-mon1.remove.this.row,]
  mon2.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$mon2[i]<-expanded.offerings[mon2.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-mon2.remove.this.row,]
  mon3.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$mon3[i]<-expanded.offerings[mon3.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-mon3.remove.this.row,]
  mon4.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$mon4[i]<-expanded.offerings[mon4.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-mon4.remove.this.row,]
  mon5.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$mon5[i]<-expanded.offerings[mon5.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-mon5.remove.this.row,]
  mon6.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$mon6[i]<-expanded.offerings[mon6.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-mon6.remove.this.row,]
  mon7.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$mon7[i]<-expanded.offerings[mon7.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-mon7.remove.this.row,]
  #TUESDAY COURSES
  tues1.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$tues1[i]<-expanded.offerings[tues1.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-tues1.remove.this.row,]
  tues2.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$tues2[i]<-expanded.offerings[tues2.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-tues2.remove.this.row,]
  tues3.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$tues3[i]<-expanded.offerings[tues3.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-tues3.remove.this.row,]
  tues4.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$tues4[i]<-expanded.offerings[tues4.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-tues4.remove.this.row,]
  tues5.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$tues5[i]<-expanded.offerings[tues5.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-tues5.remove.this.row,]
  tues6.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$tues6[i]<-expanded.offerings[tues6.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-tues6.remove.this.row,]
  tues7.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$tues7[i]<-expanded.offerings[tues7.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-tues7.remove.this.row,]
  #WEDNESDAY COURSES
  wed1.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$wed1[i]<-expanded.offerings[wed1.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-wed1.remove.this.row,]
  wed2.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$wed2[i]<-expanded.offerings[wed2.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-wed2.remove.this.row,]
  wed3.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$wed3[i]<-expanded.offerings[wed3.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-wed3.remove.this.row,]
  wed4.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$wed4[i]<-expanded.offerings[wed4.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-wed4.remove.this.row,]
  wed5.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$wed5[i]<-expanded.offerings[wed5.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-wed5.remove.this.row,]
  wed6.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$wed6[i]<-expanded.offerings[wed6.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-wed6.remove.this.row,]
  wed7.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$wed7[i]<-expanded.offerings[wed7.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-wed7.remove.this.row,]
  #THURSDAY COURSES
  thu1.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$thu1[i]<-expanded.offerings[thu1.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-thu1.remove.this.row,]
  thu2.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$thu2[i]<-expanded.offerings[thu2.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-thu2.remove.this.row,]
  thu3.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$thu3[i]<-expanded.offerings[thu3.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-thu3.remove.this.row,]
  thu4.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$thu4[i]<-expanded.offerings[thu4.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-thu4.remove.this.row,]
  thu5.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$thu5[i]<-expanded.offerings[thu5.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-thu5.remove.this.row,]
  thu6.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$thu6[i]<-expanded.offerings[thu6.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-thu6.remove.this.row,]
  thu7.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$thu7[i]<-expanded.offerings[thu7.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-thu7.remove.this.row,]
  #FRIDAY COURSES
  fri1.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$fri1[i]<-expanded.offerings[fri1.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-fri1.remove.this.row,]
  fri2.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$fri2[i]<-expanded.offerings[fri2.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-fri2.remove.this.row,]
  fri3.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$fri3[i]<-expanded.offerings[fri3.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-fri3.remove.this.row,]
  fri4.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$fri4[i]<-expanded.offerings[fri4.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-fri4.remove.this.row,]
  fri5.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$fri5[i]<-expanded.offerings[fri5.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-fri5.remove.this.row,]
  fri6.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$fri6[i]<-expanded.offerings[fri6.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-fri6.remove.this.row,]
  fri7.remove.this.row<-sample(1:nrow(expanded.offerings),1,replace = F)
  lecture.halls$fri7[i]<-expanded.offerings[fri7.remove.this.row,1]
  expanded.offerings<-expanded.offerings[-fri7.remove.this.row,]
}
rm(list = ls.str(mode = 'numeric'))
```

Any help making this code more efficient or ideas about how to accomplish building a scheduling thingy that can work with up to 3 section meetings (in the same lecture hall at the same time of day but on different days of the week) and/or allowing different courses to have different lecture durations would be greatly appreciated. Sorry again about the ugliness

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I misunderstood your intention, but would something like this help:

```
replicate(NROW(lecture.halls), sample(expanded.offerings$section, 5))
```

What it does is to draw 5 sections from `expanded.offerings` (for each day of the week) **without** replacement (so you guarantee that it will be different sections and repeat this procedure for each of lecture halls. It returns a matrix of dimension `5 x NROW(lecture.halls)` which you could further shape to your needs.

---

**Edit**

Actually you an also draw from `expanded.offerings$section` in one go and format the results yourself, which may be even faster. In this way you would guarantee that no course is selected more than once over a full week:

```
res <- sample(expanded.offerings$section, 5 * NROW(lecture.halls))
dim(res) <- c(NROW(lecture.halls), 5)
res
```

---

**Results**

```
replicate(NROW(lecture.halls), sample(expanded.offerings$section, 5)) %>% 
   t() %>%
   as_tibble(.name_repair = ~ c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
                                "Thursday", "Friday")) %>% 
   mutate(room = lecture.halls$lecture_hall) %>% 
   select(room, everything())
# A tibble: 200 x 6
   room  Monday            Tuesday              Wednesday            Thursday             Friday              
#    <chr> <chr>             <chr>                <chr>                <chr>                <chr>               
#  1 A001  Business-1035-012 English-1770-010     Engineering-1500-001 Engineering-1545-006 History-1335-028    
#  2 B001  Math-1905-016     Economics-1080-015   Writing-1155-029     Art-1125-003         Art-1080-001        
#  3 C001  Business-1155-031 Business-1950-034    English-1785-006     Business-0915-032    Physics-1275-002    
#  4 D001  History-0915-002  Physics-1500-017     Economics-1665-017   Writing-1860-049     Art-1140-019        
#  5 E001  Writing-1785-004  Economics-1695-044   Economics-1815-016   Economics-1560-031   Chemistry-1845-032  
#  6 F001  English-1680-012  Music-1725-011       Art-1140-074         English-1800-023     Physics-1935-033    
#  7 G001  History-1845-003  Art-1980-009         Biology-1770-001     Economics-1860-001   Economics-1590-091  
#  8 H001  Art-1365-029      Math-1140-165        Music-1710-016       Economics-1920-029   Business-1680-009   
#  9 I001  Biology-1410-037  Math-1515-010        Music-1935-036       Art-1140-031         Engineering-1830-006
# 10 J001  Music-1545-009    Engineering-1755-017 Music-1770-018       Business-2040-013    History-1170-076    
# # ... with 190 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach samples for all the rows at once. The subsetted rows are then transformed into a matrix and reassigned back to the `lecture.hall` data.frame:

```
# lecture hall days and periods
cols <- Reduce(function(x,y) paste0(y, x), expand.grid(1:7, c('mon','tue','wed','thu','fri')))

# do all of the sampling of expanded.offerings at once
class_selections <- sample(nrow(expanded.offerings),
                           size = nrow(lecture.halls) * (length(cols)),
                           replace = F)

# subset expanded.offerings and assign back to the lecture.halls
lecture.halls[, cols] <- matrix(unlist(expanded.offerings, use.names = F)[class_selections],
                                 ncol = length(cols))

# remove used rows form exapnded.offerings
expanded.offerings <- slice(expanded.offerings, -class_selections)

# or I would have made expanded.offerings a vector
#expanded.offerings <- unlist(expanded.offerings, use.names = F)[-class_selections]

lecture.halls

# 200 total rows; 36 variables.
#
#   lecture_hall                 mon1                 mon2                 mon3
#1          A001 Engineering-1125-009     Physics-1050-025   Chemistry-1455-022
#2          B001         Art-1875-001     English-1425-014     Physics-1335-024
#3          C001         Art-1890-042   Chemistry-1650-012        Math-1200-057
#4          D001        Math-1830-020     English-1770-004   Chemistry-1170-022
#5          E001        Math-1260-013     History-1125-023   Chemistry-2010-034
#6          F001   Chemistry-0945-043     Writing-1680-024       Music-1740-033
```

Also, here would be my full code rewrite. It takes 0.02 s on my computer compared to 3.5 s the original function did. It is also completely base.

```
set.seed(1)
# Create unique courses AKA Music-915 or English-2050 ---------------------
courses <- Reduce(function(x,y) paste(x, y, sep = '-'),
                  expand.grid(c("Math", "English", "History","Writing","Engineering","Chemistry","Biology","Business","Physics","Economics","Music","Art"),
                              sprintf("%04d",seq(900,2050,by = 15))
                              )
                  )

# Generate random sections ------------------------------------------------
course_offerings <- ceiling(8.75 * rchisq(length(courses), 0.0001, 3) + 1)


# Repeat the courses to include all sections ------------------------------

# This was group_by() and mutate() in the original. sequence() will 
# create the numbers much faster
expanded_courses <- Reduce(function(x,y) paste(x,y, sep = '-'),
                           list(rep(courses, course_offerings),
                                sprintf("%03d", sequence(course_offerings))
                                )
                           )

# Create lecture halls for the courses to be held -------------------------
lecture_halls <- Reduce(paste0,
                        expand.grid(LETTERS[1:10],
                                    sprintf("%03d",seq(1,20,by = 1)))
                        )

# Lecture Hall Days and Periods -------------------------------------------
cols <- Reduce(function(x,y) paste0(y, x),
               expand.grid(1:7,
                           c('mon','tue','wed','thu','fri')))

# do all of the sampling of expanded.offerings at once
class_selections <- sample(length(expanded_courses),
                           size = length(lecture_halls) * length(cols),
                           replace = F)

# subset expanded.offerings and assign back to the lecture.halls
class_catalog <- data.frame(lecture_halls,
                            matrix(expanded_courses[class_selections],
                                   ncol = length(cols),
                                   dimnames = list(NULL, cols))
                            , stringsAsFactors = F)

# remove used courses. Note, if we didn't have to subset, 
# we could have used sample(expanded.offerings) a couple of commands ago.
expanded_courses <- expanded_courses[-class_selections]
```